# physics simulation in erlang, how to produce graphical output

Tags: graphics, erlang

I am programming a particle system physics simulation in erlang/OTP on OS X and want to output relatively simple line graphics.

I have looked into wxWidgets but using it under OS X does not seem to be straightforward. Most of the tutorials seem to be rather outdated, too.

Should I run a GUI frontend, e.g., in javascript, that polls the data from the erlang backend? Are there other options to produce simple graphical output from erlang?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: for simple plot in erlang look [erlplot](https://github.com/psyeugenic/eplot). With wxErlang you easy show it on GUI.

Comment: To give a concrete example on how to use Erlang, cowboy and HTML5 for rendering, have a look at inaka.net/blog/2015/11/13/erlang-serpents

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you could use HTML5 cowboy/n2o/nitrogen framework and draw with n2o websocket in canvas.